# Octopus deploy hangs when trying to install TopShelf app

Tags: topshelf, octopus-deploy

I have an service where we use TopShelf. Now I would like to install the service with Octopusdeploy but I can't get it to work. The tentacle seems to hang when I'm trying to start the service. The Deploy.ps1 looks like:

```
$cmd = "$OctopusPackageDirectoryPath" + "\NameOfExe.exe"

& $cmd "stop"
& $cmd "uninstall"
& $cmd "install"
& $cmd "start"
```

It works just fine to execut that powershell script in powershell, but the tentacle gets stuck on the last step. I can see in the log that the service is stopped, uninstalled and installed but it hangs on start.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. I am trying to set up a service running quartz.net and it seems that it seems like setting quartz that's causing the problem based on some weird security settings.

Comment: We have support for topshelf services in build deploy support (https://github.com/jonnii/BuildDeploySupport). There's no need to uninstall and install your service when deploying, only if it's the first time the service is being deployed.

Comment: @jonnii, nice. I've done something similar for IIS setup and configuration inhouse.

Comment: I'd love to see your scripts to see if there's anything I can merge into BuildDeploySupport. Can you gist them?

Comment: What could be done to improve these issues in Octopus? Would adding a "take memory dump" feature when a deployment hangs have been useful in this case? Was anything written to the event log or deployment log to indicate what the problem was?

Comment: @PaulStovell, I think there are a couple of things you can do. I didn't have anything written to any log and that could be the case sometimes, I think the issue that I didn't get any information was more a problem with quartz or topshelf. Howevere, the improvements I can think of are something that indicates that a deployment takes long time, and the cancel function should be improved. When I clicked cancel it started cancelling but the agent just hang so I couldn't start a new deploy without restarting the instance. It would be nice to restart the agents from the web-ui.

Comment: Semi related, so I thought I would share.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/topshelf-discuss/KNo7-Z2_0VQ

Comment: @jonnii, I'm making my script simpler and the work in progress can be seen in this demo project: https://github.com/mastoj/DeployDemo/tree/master/DemoProject.Web/DeployScripts

Comment: Same exact setup. Using topshelf with Quartz. Octopus hangs. Nothing in the logs. Fun stuff... What actually resolved the issue for you?

Comment: FWIW, we're deploying a few different services built on top-shelf and have frequent issues where our services fail to start. We've tried hacky workarounds to ensure control returns to Windows within a few seconds but nothing seems to work. What's frustrating is you remote into the machine, start the service and everything's working fine. There's something goofy with Octopus and Topshelf...